# The left action is a group homomoprhism and tangent spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

Was reading [about Lie Groups](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~goldberg/Notes/AboutLieGroups.pdf). This texts asserts that the left action $h \to gh$ is a group homomorphism. I don't see this (already checked $\phi(fg) \neq \phi(f)\phi(g)$)

It also asserts that the canonical maps give rise to the "canonical"  isomorphisms on the tangent spaces. This should be obvious, but why?

Comment: Obviously neither left nor right multiplication is a group homomorphism. The author is simply wrong. But the conjungtion is a homomorphism and all of them are diffeomorphisms. As for the other question: I'm not really sure what exactly you mean? Are you asking about the usage of "canonical" word? It seems to me ambiguous and doesn't really matter. What is important is that for every Lie group $G$ and two points $g,h\in G$ there are auto-diffeomorphisms which map $g\mapsto h$ and thus they induce an isomorphism between tangent spaces.

Comment: @freakish, I see thank you. I thought I was not seeing something. He defined $L_{gh}$ to be canonical isomorphism for the tangent spaces, and he asserts it stems from the original group actions in the Lie Group. I know this should really simple to see, but I can't see the connection.

Comment: It's not $L_{gh}$ (or rather $L_{gh^{-1}}$) that is the isomorphism but $T_g(L_{gh^{-1}})$ where $T_g$ is a functor that maps differential maps into corresponding linear maps between tangent spaces (see the begining of the article). This is a functor in categorical sense, so it preserves map composition and identities. Thus diffeomorphisms are mapped to isomorphisms.